# What does the outer display type refer to? - display: flex; and outer display type

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, display

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#propdef-display

> - the inner display type, which defines (if it is a non-replaced    element) the kind of formatting context it generates, dictating how
>   its descendant boxes are laid out. (The inner display of a replaced
>   element is outside the scope of CSS.)
> - the outer display type, which dictates **how the principal box itself  participates in flow layout**.

[image]

Given that information, what is the value for a *flex container* and a *grid container* for "**display-outside**"?

For example, the inner display type for `display: flex;` is `flex`, but what would be its outer display type?

or, what does the outer display type refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`block`.

Display outside is equivalent to the "levelness" of a box when its parent box is a block container.

In other words, if the element's principal box of `display:flex` element is participating in a block formatting context, then the box is **block**-level and its display-outside value is "block".

Equally, the principal box of an element whose computed value for `display` is `inline-flex` will be participating in a inline formatting context and then the box is **inline**-level and its display-outside value is "inline".

Similarly for `grid` and `inline-grid`.

Comment: hi @Alohci +1 - then the outer display type means how a flex container box/grid container box would be laid out if placed inside a block container, right?

Comment: @Coder23 - That's correct.

Comment: Excellent +1 @Alohci - The documentation states that *"the outer display type, which dictates how the principal box itself participates in flow layout.*" It says "flow layout" because **all the boxes** ultimately end up being inside a block container (normal flow = flow layout = block-and-inline layout), right?

Comment: @Coder23 - Sort of. the spec contains a link to the definition of flow-layout which says "The element lays out its contents using flow layout (block-and-inline layout)." The ultimately inside a block container isn't necessary though.

Comment: that's because a block container can have either inline layout or block layout, right? @Alohci

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is there. It's correct that a block container can have either inline layout or block layout, but I'm not clear what you're inferring from that.

Comment: "The ultimately inside a block container isn't necessary thoug" - @Alohci or what do you mean here?

Comment: I mean I don't think flow-layout requires that there be a block container somewhere in the ancestry of every box in the box tree. It not even 100% clear whether it's so. The initial containing block establishes a block formatting context for the root element's box, but since the ICB is not a box, it's not by any definition I've seen, technically a block container. So if the root element is `display:flex`, the flex container box would be display-outside = block, but would not be in a block container.  It's more the definition of its layout in a _hypothetical_ block container.